# How can I get the number (ID) of a Thread in a FixedPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I know that Thread.currentThread().getName() gives me the pool name and the ID of this thread in the Pool,how can I just get the number?

This is the outcome of the line I mentioned:

pool-1-thread-1

I just need the last number.

Comment: [`Thread.currentThread().getId()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId())?

Comment: The problem is that in my code i have multiple threads runnig so the ids aren't the ones in the pool, I get values like 38,39,40, when i want 1,2 and 3.

Comment: @J.FF It sounds like you don't want the thread id per se, but rather a sequence number that's scoped to just this one thread pool. Is that right?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`, it will create a default [ThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) and this default `ThreadFactory` creates `Thread` with name like `pool-x-thread-y`.

You can custom a `ThreadFactory` and use it construct the thread pool:

```
class NumberThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {        
    int count = 0;
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, String.valueOf(count++));
    }
}
```

---

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, new NumberThreadFactory());

executor.execute(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()));  // 1
executor.execute(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()));  // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not useful for a general case but gets the job done for me:

```
Thread.currentThread().getName().substring(Thread.currentThread().getName().length()-1)
```

Comment: This will only work as olong as the `id`s have only one digit.

Comment: Yes, im aware of that but since im using a FixedThredPool with 3 threads its not really a problem. I know the solutioniis not the best but I just need those id's to be displayed in a GUI.